# How to programmatically create views in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views

How do I programmatically create views in Drupal 7?

I would like to create a custom module that would output data as a view.

Is there any documentation on how to output views from a custom module?

Comment: Do you mean you want to execute an existing view (possibly with arguments), or that you want to define and create a new view from scratch in code?

Comment: Clive, I would like to define a new view from scratch in code but to reuse the Views functionality instead of adding php code inside an existing view to avoid storing php code inside the drupal database.

Comment: I found views api is described here: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21views.api.php/7

Comment: this has some good pointers as well:  http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-default-views

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first guess was to create a desired view using UI, export it and paste the generated code into own module.
And I guess this is how admin_menu installs their admin views. You could install the module just for testing and see the contents of `/admin_menu/admin_views/views_default/`. At any rate, you would have to resort to writing a custom module and adhere to views' hooks syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good step-by-step tutorial here: http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-views-3-programmatically

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.